# simple regex extraction in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have tried using zsh regex mechanic, but it does not yield results

To test the functionality I have tried a simple regex to extract one number from a string
`% [[ "45" =~ '[0-9]' ]]` then `% echo $match` to print the result

I also tried

```
% temp="45"
% [[ temp =~ '[0-9' ]]
% echo $match[1]
```

```
% [[ temp =~ [0-9] ]]
% echo $match[1]
```

```
% [[ temp =~ [0-9] ]]
% echo $match[0]
```

```
% [[ 45 =~ [0-9] ]]
% echo $match[0]
```

```
% [[ 45 =~ [0-9] ]] && echo $match[0]
```

and so on
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This may help:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553607/pattern-matching-in-a-zsh-conditional-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add parentheses to the pattern:

```bash
> [[ '45' =~ ([0-9]) ]]
> print matched: ${match[1]}
matched: 4
```

With a variable:

```bash
> temp=string64
> [[ $temp =~ ([0-9]) ]]
> print found: ${match[1]}
found: 6
```

Or you can use the upper-case variable MATCH:

```bash
v=edittoadd98
[[ $v =~ [0-9] ]]
print found: $MATCH
found: 9
```

From the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html):

> [T]he scalar parameter `MATCH` is set to the substring that matched the pattern and the integer parameters `MBEGIN` and `MEND` to the index of the start and end, respectively, of the match in string ... [T]he array `match` is set to the substrings that matched parenthesised subexpressions and the arrays `mbegin` and `mend` to the indices of the start and end positions, respectively, of the substrings within string. The arrays are not set if there were no parenthesised subexpressions.